# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/FacesWrapper error though the required classes been added to the project classpath in RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In the process of learning RichFaces I added the related .jar files and jsf .jar files to the WEBINF/lib and to the classpath in eclipse.

Below are the files I added to the WEBINF/lib,

```
richfaces-components-api-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
javax.faces.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-digester3-3.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-bean-collections-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
common-annotations.jar
```

But when I start the tomcat it shows,

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/FacesWrapper

I found that the class file exists in javax.faces.jar file. And also I added the files to the project classpath.

But still I receive the above error.

Am I lacking any extra .jar files? Or Am I doing any wrong file integration?

Thanks

Comment: What server are you targeting/deploying to? By the way, just dropping the files in `/WEB-INF/lib` is sufficient. You really don't need to fiddle with buildpath settings. Maybe you made things worse, so I'd suggest to undo whatever you've changed in buildpath settings.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks for the answer. Well. I don't know reason why it happened. So just started a new project and set the project and it is working

Answer (score 0):

try adding javax.faces.jar in your tomcat lib folder